# Golang float arithmetic

Tags: go, floating-point, floating-accuracy

How does the float arithmetic work in Go

Playground [link](https://play.golang.org/p/eayXoOe83E)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    j := 1.021
    fmt.Println(j)
    k := j*1000
    fmt.Println(k)
    l := int(k)
    fmt.Println(l)
}

Output:
1.021
1020.9999999999999
1020
```

I was expecting `1021` to be printed, but I got `1020`

Comment: Maybe your surprise comes from ignoring that 1.021 is not exactly the fraction 1021/1000, but the nearest possible float to this fraction... Please read the literature recommended with the floating-point tag.

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies it. Interestingly, I did not understand why I got downvotes for the question. I indeed searched around and was not able to find a clear reason. Somehow I thought this was Go specific, while it seems very generic.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy yes, it is. Thanks. Interestingly that post got 811 upvotes, while mine -3.

Comment: More explanation here @ http://0.30000000000000004.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go, like everyone else, uses IEEE-754 binary floating-point arithmetic. Floating-point arithmetic is inexact for some decimal values.

References:

[Floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

[IEEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)